# Examples of hyperbolic sets of dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

I am studying the definition of hyperbolic set: a compact invariant set $\Lambda$ of a diffeomorphism $f$ such that the tangent space in each point of the set $\Lambda$ can be split in two invariant directions (stable and unstable).

However, I am having some trouble trying to figure out examples of such hyperbolic sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some standard examples:

1. Hyperbolic fixed points of a diffeomorphism: Let $f:M\to M$ be a $C^1$ diffeomorphism of a $C^\infty$ manifold and $x\in M$ be such that $f(x)=x$. Then the derivative $T_xf:T_xM\to T_xM$ is an invertible operator acting on the tangent space at $x$. $\Lambda=\{x\}$ is $f$-hyperbolic if $T_xf$ has no eigenvalues of modulus $1$.
2. In particular, if $X$ is a Banach space and $T:X\to X$ is a hyperbolic invertible operator, then $\Lambda=\{0\}$ is a $T$-hyperbolic set (see [Space of linear, continuous, hyperbolic functions is open, dense in the set of invertible functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2798482/169085)).
3. Hyperbolic periodic points of a diffeomorphism: Let $f:M\to M$ be a $C^1$ diffeomorphism of a $C^\infty$ manifold and $x\in M$ be such that $f^p(x)=x$ for some $p\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Then the derivative $T_xf^p:T_xM\to T_xM$ is an invertible operator acting on the tangent space at $x$. $\Lambda=\{x\}$ is $f$-hyperbolic if $T_xf^p$ has no eigenvalues of modulus $1$.
4. State space of an Anosov diffeomorphism: Let $f:M\to M$ be a $C^1$ diffeomorphism of a compact $C^\infty$ manifold. $f$ is Anosov iff $\Lambda=M$ is $f$-hyperbolic.
5. In particular, if $A$ is a $d\times d$ invertible matrix with integer entries whose inverse also is with integer entries, then it defines an diffeomorphism of the torus $\mathbb{T}^d$. If $A$ has no eigenvalues of modulus $1$, then ($A$ is Anosov and) $\Lambda$is $A$-hyperbolic (see my answer in [Examples of conjugate-like structures across mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4132091/169085), or [Lyapunov exponent for 2D map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2796589/169085), or [A question on hyperbolic toral automorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4126880/169085), or [What's so hyperbolic about hyperbolic sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4294133/169085)).
6. There is a diffeomorphism $f$ of a two dimensional closed disk, called Smale's horseshoe map, that has a Cantor set $\Lambda$ as a (compact invariant) hyperbolic set. (see [How does Smale's horseshoe map work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3474791/169085) or [What's the point of a Horseshoe map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/357034/169085)).
7. The Smale-Williams solenoid $\Lambda$ can be obtained as the attractor of a diffeomorphism of a solid torus. This diffeomorphism stretches and makes thinner the donut; see p.2-5 of Milnor's notes available at [https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~jack/DYNOTES/dn2.pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ejack/DYNOTES/dn2.pdf). $\Lambda$ is a hyperbolic set for this particular diffeomorphism, and along the direction the diffeomorphism makes the donut thinner it looks like a Cantor set. (Also see [Solenoid is hyperbolic set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3470966/169085))